# parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9

Tags: json, jq

I understand that jq search needs to be blocked by `{}` and the key needs to be encased with `"`, for example:

```
{
  "id": 36815684
}
```

But if I have something like this:

```
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1452786798
```

I get this error:

> parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9

Do I need to fall back to `sed/awk/perl ..` or is there a more elegant way of using jq?

Comment: That's not JSON... that looks like an http header... `jq` is for processing JSON.

Comment: Can you provide an example with sample input and expected output? I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from not using jq at all, you have two main options:

(1) pre-processing the non-JSON to make it JSON

(2) using the -R command-line option, e.g.

```
echo "X-RateLimit-Reset: 1452786798" | jq -R 'split(":")'

[
  "X-RateLimit-Reset",
  " 1452786798"
]
```

Thus, if you know the value is going to be numeric:

```
echo "X-RateLimit-Reset: 1452786798" |
  jq -Rc 'split(":") | {(.[0]) : (.[1]|tonumber)}'
{"X-RateLimit-Reset":1452786798}
```

Note that although the "j" in jq is for JSON, jq (with the -R option) does  just fine for text-processing.